# Map doesn't respond on mouse clicks with Google Maps API V3 and QWebView

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, qwebview

**EDIT 4**

All this while I was thinking that it is the markers problem, that they do not get dragged!
Now I have realized, that NO mouse click works on the map **when it is displayed in Qt widget**.

The following code, I pasted in an HTML file and opened through Firefox, this worked flawlessly! and the same doesn't respond when I click on the map on QtWidget :rolleyes:

Can anyone confirm this for me or tell me what wrong I am doing?

Google Maps JavaScript API Example

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var map;    
var latlng            = new google.maps.LatLng (34.7607233, -117.0107599);

var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer ();;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService ();

var pointsArray       = new Array();
var arrayToBeReturned = new Array();

function initialize ()
{
    var myOptions = 
    {
        zoom:8,
        center:latlng,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map (document.getElementById ("map"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap (map); 

    google.maps.event.addListener (map, "click", function ()
                        {
                            alert("You clicked the map.");
                        });
    }

</script> 
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<div id="map" style="width: 341px; height: 271px"></div>
<div id="directionsPanel" style="float:right;width:30%;height 100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

Add this class in the source file where you are "loading" the HTML file (containing Javascript API) in the Qt widget.

```
class myWebPage : public QWebPage
{
    virtual QString userAgentForUrl(const QUrl& url) const {
        return "Chrome/1.0";
    }
};
```

Then in your own class in the same source file, add the ***setPage*** function call as shown below and see the magic happen!

```
MainScreen::MainScreen(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)
{
        ...
    ***map->setPage (new myWebPage());***
    map->load (QUrl("./index.html") ) ;
};
```

Comment: Though the people working with Google API **V2** don't need this code, because this problem doesn't exist with API **V2**.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong place for the events :) In the references each object have their own events. You can see the ones for markers here:

[http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker][1]

I have used the dragend event plenty of times and it works smoothly.

The code to do it could be:

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
        document.getElementById("txtLatitude").value = marker.getPosition().lat();
        document.getElementById("txtLongitude").value = marker.getPosition().lng();
    });
```

[1]: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Markermap = new

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and report back.

Comment: See the edits in the OP :( It still doesn't work. What's the point that I am missing?

Comment: If that is the code you are using you are not calling any code in your events. I have edited my answer to reflect what you could do :) If this still doesn't work please state if you are getting an error.

Comment: I had that line `map.closeInfoWindow();` previously in my code, but since it didn't do anything, I removed it. And I am not getting any error anywhere. Where is the error displayed BTW? Secondly, the draggable property worked fine with the V2 API. It is only in the V3 API, that it is creating problems.

Comment: Que: Is it necessary to have the "addListner" function for making the marker move?

Answer (score -1):

```
google.maps.event.addListener (initialPointMarker, 'click', 
                                  function () { map.closeInfoWindow(); });
```

How about single quotes around the click arguement