# Google map showing, but disabled

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3

I basically have a google map in my site, [here](http://rentauto-sofia.com/#contact) you can see it while it still doesn't work. (When it starts working this link will no longer be relevant.

Here is my **js**:

```
function initMap() {
    let uluru = {lat: 42.734718, lng: 23.293138};
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 16,
        center: uluru
    });
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru,
        map: map
    });
}
```

And **html**:

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBwhMwCcXQf_P_5zApM-yeg02XkWbUEAHQ&callback=initMap"></script>
```

I cannot open the map in full screen, neither can I zoom in and out. I can really do nothing but look at it. Also there are no errors in the console.
I checked whether there is something with a higher z-index than the map, but there didn't seem to be anything suspicious.
You are free to inspect the page ([here](http://rentauto-sofia.com/#contact)) and I'd be glad if you could somehow help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184240/map-doesnt-respond-on-mouse-clicks-with-google-maps-api-v3-and-qwebview I hope this post is helpful to you?

Comment: The posted code doesn't exhibit the issue ([working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/m7hc17ce/)).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, not (just) a link to your non-working site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly disabling pointer events on the `map` div on line 1937 in your CSS file http://rentauto-sofia.com/css/style.css

```
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Remove the `pointer-events: none` line and your map will work.

Comment: That solved the problem. How didn't I think of that. Thanks